# Sort a table data based on name and display using javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Whenever the page is loading, the data from ShipmentDetails.xml must be loaded and displayed in sorted order.

[image]

### ShipmentDetails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<shipment>
    <name>Charles</name>
    <shipmentId>46789056</shipmentId>
    <source>India</source>
    <destination>North America</destination>
    <startDate>05/06/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>26/06/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

<shipment>
    <name>Aryan</name>
    <shipmentId>46789696</shipmentId>
    <source>Delhi</source>
    <destination>Greece</destination>
    <startDate>09/06/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>30/06/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

<shipment>
    <name>Edward</name>
    <shipmentId>98767894</shipmentId>
    <source>Pune</source>
    <destination>Italy</destination>
    <startDate>25/06/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>05/07/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

    <shipment>
    <name>Aster</name>
    <shipmentId>88950075</shipmentId>
    <source>Italy</source>
    <destination>California</destination>
    <startDate>25/08/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>06/09/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

<shipment>
    <name>Malika</name>
    <shipmentId>88950075</shipmentId>
    <source>Japan</source>
    <destination>China</destination>
    <startDate>25/07/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>29/07/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

<shipment>
    <name>Vikrant</name>
    <shipmentId>98765240</shipmentId>
    <source>New york</source>
    <destination>Chennai</destination>
    <startDate>03/07/2017</startDate>
    <deliveredDate>10/07/2017</deliveredDate>
</shipment>

</catalog>
```

This is the below code I have used to load the data:-

```
function loadDataAndShowMessage() {
  var xhttp;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }



  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ShipmentDetails.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();

}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var count = 0;
  var strTable = "<table border='1' id='resultTable'><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>ShipmentId</th><th>Source</th><th>Destination</th><th>Start Date</th><th>Delivered Date</th></tr</thead><tbody>";
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("shipment");
  //var enteredText = document.getElementById("name").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var shipmentId = x[i].getElementsByTagName("shipmentId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var source = x[i].getElementsByTagName("source")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var destination = x[i].getElementsByTagName("destination")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var startDate = x[i].getElementsByTagName("startDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var delDate = x[i].getElementsByTagName("deliveredDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    strTable += "<tr><td id=\"name\">" + name + "</td>"+"<td>" + shipmentId + "</td><td>"
    + source + "</td><td>" + destination + "</td><td>"
    + startDate + "</td><td>" + delDate + "</td></tr>";

  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strTable + "</tbody></table>";

}


   Create a file named index.html
Create a file named script.js
The xml file name should be ShipmentDetails.xml.
Get the details about the shipments from the xml file using AJAX and sort them based on name in ascending order.
```

### Sorted Details should be displayed in tabular form when the page is loaded.

Sample Screenshot 1:
Whenever the page is loading, the data from ShipmentDetails.xml must be loaded and displayed in sorted order.

Answer (score 3):

Your updated **myFunction**

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var count = 0;
  var strTable = "<table border='1' id='resultTable'><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>ShipmentId</th><th>Source</th><th>Destination</th><th>Start Date</th><th>Delivered Date</th></tr</thead><tbody>";
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("shipment");

  //convert HTMLCollection to an array and run sort method on it
  x = Array.from(x);
  x.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var textB = b.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    if (textA < textB) return -1;
    if (textA > textB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  //var enteredText = document.getElementById("name").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var shipmentId = x[i].getElementsByTagName("shipmentId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var source = x[i].getElementsByTagName("source")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var destination = x[i].getElementsByTagName("destination")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var startDate = x[i].getElementsByTagName("startDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var delDate = x[i].getElementsByTagName("deliveredDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    strTable += "<tr><td id=\"name\">" + name + "</td>"+"<td>" + shipmentId + "</td><td>"
    + source + "</td><td>" + destination + "</td><td>"
    + startDate + "</td><td>" + delDate + "</td></tr>";

  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strTable + "</tbody></table>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you first need to sort the array

```
x.sort(function(a, b) {
 var textA = a.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 var textB = b.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

then loop over it , hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I first converted the xml to json and then used sort method of arrays and used the localeCompare function to compare them with, the json format also helps more to build up the template easier with template literals

```js
// you no longer need ActiveXObject
function loadDataAndShowMessage() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
  xhr.onload = () => myFunction(xhr.responseXML)
  xhr.open('GET', getUrl())
  xhr.send()
}

function xml2obj(node) {
  const obj = {}
  for (const child of node.children)
    obj[child.nodeName] = child.textContent
  return obj
}

function saferHTML(templateData) {
  let tpl = templateData[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    const arg = arguments[i]

    // Escape special characters in the substitution.
    tpl += arg.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;")

    // Don't escape special characters in the template.
    tpl += templateData[i];
  }
  return tpl;
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  // converts a nodeList to an array with spread (...)
  const shipments = [...xml.getElementsByTagName('shipment')]
    .map(xml2obj)
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    .map(shipment => saferHTML`<tr>
      <td class=name>${shipment.name}</td>
      <td>${shipment.shipmentId}</td>
      <td>${shipment.destination}</td>
      <td>${shipment.deliveredDate}</td>
    </tr>`)
    .join('')

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Destionation</th>
          <th>Delivery</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ${shipments}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `
}

loadDataAndShowMessage()


// Dummy fn sense there is nowhere to get the data
function getUrl() {
return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><shipment><name>Charles</name><shipmentId>46789056</shipmentId><source>India</source><destination>North America</destination><startDate>05/06/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>26/06/2017</deliveredDate></shipment><shipment><name>Aryan</name><shipmentId>46789696</shipmentId><source>Delhi</source><destination>Greece</destination><startDate>09/06/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>30/06/2017</deliveredDate></shipment><shipment><name>Edward</name><shipmentId>98767894</shipmentId><source>Pune</source><destination>Italy</destination><startDate>25/06/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>05/07/2017</deliveredDate></shipment><shipment><name>Aster</name><shipmentId>88950075</shipmentId><source>Italy</source><destination>California</destination><startDate>25/08/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>06/09/2017</deliveredDate></shipment><shipment><name>Malika</name><shipmentId>88950075</shipmentId><source>Japan</source><destination>China</destination><startDate>25/07/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>29/07/2017</deliveredDate></shipment><shipment><name>Vikrant</name><shipmentId>98765240</shipmentId><source>New york</source><destination>Chennai</destination><startDate>03/07/2017</startDate><deliveredDate>10/07/2017</deliveredDate></shipment></catalog>`]))
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
```